# Handling flexible command requests

Tags: c#, oop

I have a quite complex object to which I wish to add the capability to execute several commands. Each command could require different numerical parameters; their number (parameters) must be variable, in order to arrange the room for very different processing requests. The solution I have sketched is following:

```
public enum ProcessingMethod {NONE, THIS, THAT, ETC};    
public interface IProcessing
{
    void Process(ProcessingMethod ProcType, Double[] Parameters);
}
```

This way the object implementing the interface:

1. Is able to recognize what kind of processing is requested by means of the first parameter;
2. Knows how many parameters have been passed from the array length;
3. Being passed only numerical parameters, can simply cast from double to handle 
   integers, long, float.
4. Encapsulates the knowledge required to deal with the parameters taking in account the position

This design seems to be simple and able to get the job done, but looking at it, I have the strong feeling that this design is a symptom of inflexible procedural reasoning. I was trying to think better in terms of the Command design pattern but it seems to me quite an overkill. Furthermore, it does not match exactly my needs.

My question is: there is a simple solution to meet these requirements in a more oo design?

Comment: Why you don't **pack parameters in a class hierarchy**? `IProcessing.Process()` will accept base class `ProcessingParameters` and cast to right derived type. It'll **GREATLY** reduce chances you pass wrong parameters because of position (and you won't be limited to numeric values). Better solutions exist but we need more context. Then **remove that "smelly" `enum`**. You may need a Strategy or simply multiple implementations, again it depends why you're trying to do that.

Comment: First of all look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx)

Comment: BTW IMO the point isn't if it's flexible or not (until it gets job done you - may - don't need to change it). Point is that it's error prone. Wrong parameters order isn't detected and who uses that interface must go to documentation to see #1 is A and #2 is B. It's (even) worse than a method with many parameters (where at least you can - quickly - consult parameter's name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems with your approach:

1. There is no guarantee the implementing object will have an implementation of each `ProcessingMethod`
2. There is no way to match up number of parameters with a given `ProcessingMethod`

For both these reasons, I would split out your various "Process" methods into their own function calls to ensure parameter count safety (the first problem is far less important):

```
public interface IProcessing
{
    void ProcessNone();
    void ProcessThis(double x);
    void ProcessThat(double x, int y);
    ...
}
```

An interface defines a contract that says what your object can do, and provides compile-time safety to ensure the implementors at least have functions with those signatures. Its a much safer approach.

If you really want to avoid this kind of interface, however, your implementation seems reasonable.

Comment: I appreciate your points; however I am sure the server object will deal in the future with *a lot* of possible commands; I am unable to anticipate what, when, how many parameters, and so on. My aim is: to arrange all the flexibility I can  given my lack of knowledge of future implementations; start to code asap the first commands specified so far.

Comment: @Daniel, You add more functions to your interface in that case, which then forces the implementation to deal with these new functions, etc. You could also write a function that returned an object and took an object (absolute flexibility in many senses) but thats also a bad idea (for hopefully obvious reasons). Type-safety is a language feature you should take advantage of. In other words, you should have all the flexibility you need with a strong interface. Note that new commands require changing your enum, which *still* changes your old interface. Might as well do it the right way!

Comment: My doubt is related to a factoring metrics issue: in "Programming .NET components" I have found warnings against too granular interfaces. At the end of the day I could have an interface with hundreds of processing methods.

Comment: @Daniel Sounds like a different design issue if you have 100s of ways to do something on a server. Regardless, you are just asking for someone to do it wrong with the single function call + enum approach. Prepare for a lot of invalid arguments in that case.